# Incomplete retrieving multidimensional array from a Form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I've created a form that produce 3 dimensions array.

```
$_POST['tgt'][1234]['target_produk'];
```

The result is like this,

```
110
array (size=9)
  'dr' => string '1020' (length=4)
  'target_harnal' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_vesicare' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_perdipine' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_dorner' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_mycamine' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_nasea' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_prograf' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_max' => string '2' (length=1)
111
array (size=9)
  'dr' => string '1019' (length=4)
  'target_harnal' => string '1' (length=1)
  'target_vesicare' => string '1' (length=1)
  'target_perdipine' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_dorner' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_mycamine' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_nasea' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_prograf' => string '0' (length=1)
  'target_max' => string '1' (length=1)
112
array (size=1)
  'dr' => string '1018' (length=4)
```

I tried to check are the data has been sent successfully by create a simple foreach and a var_dump,

```
public function target_process(){
    $i=1;
    foreach($_POST['tgt'] AS $data){
        //set_time_limit(0);
        echo $i;
        $id = $data['dr'];
        var_dump($data);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The process always stop at **112th loop**.
Is it because of the time limit or the memory or any other possible reason?

I've also tried to create a manual array (not from a form),
and it could loop as usual until the end.

Thank you.

Comment: Turn on the error reporting by `ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);` putting this at the top of the script. And check what is causing the loop break.

Comment: @AlokPatel Thanks for your response,.ok, i'll try it.